# Error "undefined index: metodo" al recorrer una matriz

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Necesito ayuda para representar dos porcentajes en un gráfico.

Éste es mi código:

```
     $operacionmp = ($mp / $total) *100;
      $operacionefectivo = ($efectivo / $total) *100;
        
      $infos = [
        ['carro1' => ['metodo' => 'efectivo', 'valores' => $operacionefectivo]],
        ['carro2' => ['metodo' => 'mercadopago', 'valores' => $operacionmp]],
    ];
    
    
    
      foreach ($infos as $info) {
        $puntos[] = ['name' => $info['metodo'], 'y' => floatval($info['valores'])];
      }

  $datas =  json_encode($puntos);
```

El problema es que no recorre el arreglo:

> Error: **Undefined index: metodo**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que tienes es debido a que no estás considerando correctamente la profundidad de la matriz multidimensional que has creado:

```
$infos = [
  [
    'carro1' => [
      'metodo' => 'efectivo',
      'valores' => $operacionefectivo,
    ],
  ],
  [
    'carro2' => [
      'metodo' => 'mercadopago',
      'valores' => $operacionmp,
    ],
  ],
];
```

Cada iteración del bucle obtiene un elemento en `$info`. El primero sería el siguiente:

```
[
  'carro1' => [
    'metodo' => 'efectivo',
    'valores' => $operacionefectivo,
  ],
],
```

Como puedes ver no tiene el índice llamado `metodo`, si no que tiene un único índice llamado `carro1` y su contenido son los datos que buscas.

En el segundo caso la cosa es similar, pero el nombre del índice es `carro2`:

```
[
  'carro2' => [
    'metodo' => 'mercadopago',
    'valores' => $operacionmp,
  ],
],
```

La solución más sencilla a tu problema (manteniendo la matriz tal y como está) es iterar el contenido del elemento obtenido en `$info` para obtener su contenido:

```
foreach ($infos as $info) {
    foreach ($info as $carro) {
        $puntos[] = [
            'name' => $carro['metodo'],
            'y' => floatval($carro['valores']),
        ];
    }
}
```

Por otro lado, podrías modificar la matriz de datos para tener el formato que tu código original necesita:

```
$infos = [
    'carro1' => [
        'metodo' => 'efectivo',
        'valores' => $operacionefectivo
    ],
    'carro2' => [
        'metodo' => 'mercadopago',
        'valores' => $operacionmp,
    ],
];
```

O, de manera condensada, como tienes en tu código:

```
$infos = [
    'carro1' => [ 'metodo' => 'efectivo', 'valores' => $operacionefectivo ],
    'carro2' => [ 'metodo' => 'mercadopago', 'valores' => $operacionmp ],
];
```

Ahora cada elemento obtenido en `$info` tendrá los índices deseados.